# Open other window with button in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to open another window , when user use an pushButton!
I used qt5 designer for UI.
So that is my main window code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from sas import Ui_MainWindow
from langs import Ui_MainWindow2

class langse(QDialog, Ui_MainWindow2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(langse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class myprog(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myprog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(lambda:self.enableChoose())
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.onchbtn)
        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(lambda:self.disableChoose())
    def enableChoose(self):
        self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(True)

    def disableChoose(self):
        self.pushButton_5.setEnabled(False)

    def onchbtn(self):
        widget = langse()
        widget.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = myprog()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But when i use Choose button i will see this  error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 35, in onchbtn
    widget = langse()
  File "./main.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "/home/amirrezaw/p/GTranslate/langs.py", line 336, in setupUi
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
AttributeError: 'langse' object has no attribute 'setCentralWidget'
```

I need to use some function for new window so i did it, But i heard QDialog can do it(run another window) but you can't use functions and code for objects...
Thanks.

Comment: The `Ui_MainWindow2` is not a `QDialog`, it is a `QMainWindow`. If you want a `QDialog`, you must change the top-level widget in Qt Designer.

Comment: @ekhumoro You are right! I test it but now it is another error: 'AttributeError: 'langse' object has no attribute 'exec_''

Comment: The attribute error means you did not change the top-level widget in Qt Designer to a `QDialog`, or the `langse` class does not inherit `QDialog`.

Comment: @ekhumoro No, I don't want to use QDialog, I changed `langse` class to `class langse(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow2):` ... i don't know what is problem.

Comment: You need `QDialog` if you want to use `exec`. If you use `QMainWindow`, you will have to do `self.widget = langse(); self.widget.show()`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks, I did it but after run new window, there is nothing in this window. It should show some checkBox... !

Comment: Did you set a layout on the window? It is difficult to say what the problem might be without seeing any code.